# The best overload method has invalid arguments

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf

[image: Configuration]I have added a service Reference named as ServiceReference2

While in wcf serrvice i have these Code below.

IShowDetails

```
namespace WcfService1
{

    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IShowDetails
    {
        [OperationContract]
        List<UserDetails> DisplayDetails(UserDetails User);

    }
}
```

ShowDetails

```
namespace WcfService1
{
    public class ShowDetails:IShowDetails
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
        public List<UserDetails> DisplayDetails(UserDetails User)
        {
            //Code
            return result;
        }
    }

}
```

I used this wcf service reference to host a web application. Where in the Web.Config added the

```
<endpoint address="http://localhost:8426/WcfService1/ShowDetails.svc"
    binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IShowDetails"
    contract="ServiceReference2.IShowDetails" name="BasicHttpBinding_IShowDetails" />
```

Now in one of my aspx.cs page i have these code.

```
ServiceReference2.ShowDetailsClient objDisplayUser = new ServiceReference2.ShowDetailsClient();
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        UserDetails User = new UserDetails();
        List<UserDetails> result = objDisplayUser.DisplayDetails(User);

    }
```

When i do F12(go to definition) for ShowDetailsClient(Metadata) i get these lines

```
namespace ServiceReference2
{
    [GeneratedCode("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")]
    [DebuggerStepThrough]
    public class ShowDetailsClient : ClientBase<IShowDetails>, IShowDetails
    {
        public ShowDetailsClient();
        public ShowDetailsClient(string endpointConfigurationName);
        public ShowDetailsClient(Binding binding, EndpointAddress remoteAddress);
        public ShowDetailsClient(string endpointConfigurationName, EndpointAddress remoteAddress);
        public ShowDetailsClient(string endpointConfigurationName, string remoteAddress);

        public UserDetails[] DisplayDetails(UserDetails User);
    }
}
```

So in my aspx.cs page i am getting an error

The best overload  method has invalid arguments.

As i see **public List DisplayDetails(UserDetails User)** and  **public UserDetails[] DisplayDetails(UserDetails User);** looks different. How to overcome this?

Comment: When you add a service reference from visual studio click on Advance button and change collection type from System.Array to List

Comment: I have added it already how to change it now?

Comment: Should i change to System.Collections.Array.List? or System.Collection.Generic.List?

Comment: Isn't it strange? Although there is a mismatch in return type of a method, it complains about invalid arguments! Can anyone clarify?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Add Service Reference]

When adding your service reference, did you click Advanced -> selected System.Collections.Generic.List and shown in the image below.